# Angular: remove duplicate elements inside a http call

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to remove the duplicates trought a map function but I can't see my mistake, it returs me always an 'HTTP ERROR'

```
 getListType():Observable<any> {         
             return this.http.post<any>(URL, params, httpOptions)
        .pipe(                  
               map((result: any) => {      

                          returnarray=[];

                          return result.array.forEach(function(item,index,array) {

                                if (this.returnarray.indexOf(item) == -1) {                                                                         
                                      this.returnarray.push(item);
                                } 

                                if   (index === array.length -1) {                                                    
                                      console.log(this.returnarray);
                                      return  this.result.array;
                                } 
                          }); 

              }),
              catchError(err => this.handleError(err)) 
        );        
      }

      private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
            return throwError("HTTP ERROR");
      };
```

Comment: Where is `returnarray` initialized?  You could add a try/catch around the body of the map and log the error to see what it is.

Comment: thank you , I updated my code the problem is that I receiving an undefined array, probably i am using wronge the return, any idea ?

Comment: you did not return the array from map function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 getListType():any {         
         return this.http.post<any>(URL, params, httpOptions)
    .pipe(                  
          map((result: any) => {                        
                      const returnarray=[];

                      result.data.forEach(function(item,index) {

                            if (returnarray.indexOf(item) == -1) {                                                                         
                                  returnarray.push(item);
                            } 

                            if   (index === array.length -1) {                                                    
                                  console.log(returnarray);
                                  return  result.array;
                            } 
                      });
                      return returnarray;

          }),
          catchError(err => this.handleError(err)) 
    );        
  }
```

Comment: it works, thank you!!! 
but i can't understand why :-( forEach is async function, returnarray could be returns a null value ?

Comment: FYI, even though `forEach` takes a callback, it is synchronous: it will call the callback on every element before returning.

Answer (score 0):

1. `returnarray=[]` this should be initialized with const: typescript should throw an error at this point;
2. You should probably use filter instead of forEach, this would do the trick:

```
return result.array.filter((item,index,array) => array.indexOf(item) ==-1);
```